# crop an image using canvas - result is small image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to crop an image using canvas.
Original image is 2217 x 790.
Loading on page it is scaled to 1515 x 540
Canvas is 960 x 540.
Both image and canvas are on center of screen, so aligned horizontally.
I need to crop central area - 960 x 540.

```
var img = document.getElementById("imgt");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasa");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var a = $('#imgt').width() - 960;
var a = a/2; // this is 277.7...

ctx.drawImage(img, a, 0, 960, 540, 0, 0, 960, 540);
//also tried:
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 960, 540, 0, 0, 960, 540);

var newimg = new Image();
newimg.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

var dl = document.createElement("a");
dl.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
dl.download = true;
document.body.appendChild(dl);
dl.click();
```

Downloading `newimg` what I see - it is `300 x 150` !

Comment: does setting the width and height attributes on canvas like "width='960' height='540'" work?

Comment: @ibowankenobi, yes its css is `960 x 540` and inspecting it in console - it is `960 x 540`. Also, visually it is that. I have no idea where the `300 x 150` comes from.

Comment: Those are the default height and width values for the canvas. That seems suspect that the canvas area isn't changed. Do you set it with a percentage?

Comment: I'm adding the answer and stackoveflow is complaing about fiddle just a sec.

Comment: @rlemon, see my update code, pls. And no, canvas size is not set as percentage but in css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment for differences between width attribute and width as style. They are not exactly the same. Besides, I just made a fiddle since you didn't and I don't get the same behavior! The downloaded image is 960 * 540

[HERE - fires with delay](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/rah2ddu1/12/)

[ONLOAD](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/rah2ddu1/26/)

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = "960";
  canvas.height="540";
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(document.images[0], 0, 0, 960, 540, 0, 0, 960, 540);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = "image.jpeg";
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  a.click();
},5000);
```

Comment: I moved `960 x 540` from css to canvas attributes and resulting image is `960 x 540` and that's ok now but the image is zoommed in - very bad quality?

Comment: You can add additional encoder quality value for toDataURL method, default is 0.92 or something like that.

Comment: hmm... `0.92` should be enough, but anyway, if the resulting image is zoomed - and keeping `960 x 540` - it MUST be in lower quality. Have you any idea why it is zoomed?

Comment: My fiddle does not show a zoomed image. I cannot reproduce the behavior you are getting at all.

Comment: In fact your image is zoomed too. please check.

Comment: the image you see on the fiddle is the img element. When I look at the downloaded image it is 960*540 as stated in the file properties and 150kB. I think what you want is to crop the image in a way that the aspect ratio is preserved. But this is not what is asked by your question.

Comment: and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/rah2ddu1/33/) the same example, but smaller (so1/4 the original size).

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to crop an area from a source image, and draw it into a canvas without breaking the aspect ratio *and* not hardcoding the dimensions into the routine, you can do this:

```
const canvasAspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;

const cropWidth = canvas.width;
const cropHeight = cropWidth / canvasAspectRatio;
const sx = img.width / 2 - cropWidth / 2;
const sy = img.height / 2 - cropHeight / 2;

ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, cropWidth, cropHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = document.getElementById('img');

const canvasAspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
// Crop central canvas sized rectangle area into canvas
const cropWidth = canvas.width;
const cropHeight = cropWidth / canvasAspectRatio; // Here you should calculate the height based on aspect ratio instead of assuming it matches that of the canvas
const sx = img.width / 2 - cropWidth / 2;
const sy = img.height / 2 - cropHeight / 2;

ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, cropWidth, cropHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#img {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="540"></canvas>
<img id="img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/2217x790">
```